# Action failed: lightning:button$controller$handleClick [d.run is not a function]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, dynamic, onclick, create-component

I have a lightning component called modal which is used in another component called Split, the modal takes an array of buttons to render them (and does some more)
I have a working version of it in another component and wanted to use it again. But for some reason I receive the

> Action failed: lightning:button$controller$handleClick [d.run is not a function]

Everytime I click the button.

The modal component takes the array of buttons like this:

```
let btns = [];      
btns.push(['lightning:button', {
    'label': 'Cancel',
    'onclick': cmp.getReference('c.onCancelClick'),
    'class': 'slds-button '
}]);
btns.push(['lightning:button', {
    'label': 'Confirm',
    'onclick': cmp.getReference('c.onConfirmClick'),
    'class': 'slds-button slds-button_brand'
}]);

let modal = cmp.find('confirmationDialog');          
modal.set('v.Buttons', btns);
```

The functions referenced in the onclick events are in the Split component.

Once the buttons are passed, they get created by

```
$A.createComponents
```

which works as expected. But clicking them gives the error.

For some reason it crashes in Google Chrome 
(Version 64.0.3282.167 (64-Bit))

works fine in Firefox (52.5.2 (32-bit))

And Edge says

> Action failed: lightning:button$controller$handleClick [Object doesn't support property or method 'run']

And as mentioned before, it works in the other component (in all three browsers)

Can someone help me, fix this

PS.: All my components are API Version 42.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is was, maybe a caching issue.

I created a new Component and copied everything over, that worked already.
Then I tried using my first component again, which worked for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was missing the exclamation point in action in the component definition:

incorrect:
onclick = "{ c.someEvent }"

correct:
onclick = "{**!** c.someEvent}"